# Equalise Height of a Sibling with CSS only?

Tags: css, height, siblings

Is there a way of making a div the same height as a sibling just with CSS, or is this only achievable with javascript?

In the example i have two divs in a wrapper div, and I would like the one on the left to be the same size as the one on the right.

Code is below.

```css
#wrapper {width: 50%; height; 200px;}
#box1 {background: red;}
#box2 {background: blue; height: 100px;}
.box {float: left; color: white; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box" id="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">Box 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the *wrapper* (this works because `align-items` property is `stretch` by default) - see demo below:

```css
#wrapper {display: flex;width: 50%; height; 200px;}
#box1 {background: red;}
#box2 {background: blue; height: 100px;}
.box {float: left; color: white; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box" id="box1">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">Box 2</div>
</div>
```